# Info on Symplectic/Orthogonal groups of Gl(n,R); R a ring, not necessarily division ring.

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi, Everyone:

Does anyone know anything about orthogonal and symplectic groups

associated to Gl(n,R)? I am using symplectic/orthogonal in what I think

is the standard sense;  I mean, we have an R-module R_M  (left- or right- ), and

symplectic /quadratic forms q_S , q_Q respectively . Then the symplectic/orthogonal group

associated with (R_M,Q) is defined to be the subgroup of Gl(n,R) that preserves q_S, resp. q_Q.

I have checked Artin, I Hungerfor(d) Algebra--even Schaum's :) .

Thanks for ideas, refs.

Comment: Is there something specific you want to know?  It is a rather big subject, and it is hard to say anything nontrivial about totally general rings...

Comment: Are these linear algebraic groups defined over Z? If so you can consider them as group schemes over any ring.

Comment: To give you an idea of how hard it is to do linear algebra over rings that aren't fields, let's forget symplectic/orthogonal groups for a second and consider $G_n = SL_n(\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}])$.  In an absolute tour de force, Suslin proved that $G_n$ is generated by elementary matrices for $n$ at least $3$ (and, in particular, is finitely generated).  However, for $n=2$ it is not known whether or not $G_n$ is generated by elementary matrices or finitely generated, though a deep theorem of Krstic-McCool shows that it is not finitely presentable.

Comment: In addition to Andy Putnam's comment, you might want to have a look at the related question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59884/for-which-rings-r-is-sl-nr-generated-by-transvections that I asked some time ago.

Answer (score 2):

Your goal appears to require  a somewhat different approach, at least for noncommutative rings; see the paper [Lie algebras and Lie groups over noncommutative rings](http://pages.uoregon.edu/arkadiy/noncomloopalg.pdf) by Berenstein and Retakh and references therein. The said paper concentrates more on Lie algebras than on Lie groups but still seems close enough to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay: I am actually interested in working with the ring H_1(Sg,Z) , with Sg the
 orientable genus-g surface, Z the integers and q being the intersection 2-form. I have tried to extract some info from the naturality of the reduction map between H_*(Sg,Z) and H_*(Sg,Z/2) with little success.

Answer (score 1):

The book by Hahn and O'Meara titled The Classical Groups and K-Theory could be useful for you.